# Best approach for some project handled on different domains eg .com and .co.uk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a Create `React` App Project that will be pointed to two different domains: `.com` and `.co.uk`.

I want do some localisation eg if `.co.uk` currency will be set as punds, email address will go to uk mailboxes etc.

What is the best way to do this? I thought `window.location.href` value passed by wrapping my routes in the context in `App.js` but having some issues with use effect and not sure if this is the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use environment variables - this also allows for easy debugging for either version. This will require you to build the project twice for every website update - one version for .co.uk and the other for .com.

Setting an environment variable can be done through the `.env` file (depending on if you want it to be local you can use `.env.local`, if you want it to be only on production you can use `.env.production` and if you want to keep your production values local you can use `.env.production.local`) or via prepending the environment value before build, like so `REACT_APP_COUNTRY=uk yarn build`.

For the variables to be accessible in your application you will have to make sure they start with `REACT_APP_`. You can access them in your project with `process.env.REACT_APP_COUNTRY` (you do not need to import/install any libraries).

If you have a CI/CD set up this will be easier - you just need to create two separate pipelines to deploy a version with `REACT_APP_COUNTRY=uk` to the .co.uk site and a version with `REACT_APP_COUNTRY=us` to the .com site.

Comment: thats great, how do I set the country though and know within the app if the domain is com or .co.uk to set the env variables?

Comment: You will need to set the variables on build, as I've mentioned, and the deploy the right version to the given subdomain. You will need two separate builds.